# Docker SELinux Error on mounting NFS volume to container

Tags: nfs, docker

I've created a NFS volume with

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=preisschild-server-2.lan,rw --opt device=:/mnt/tank/MariaDB MariaDBData
```

which seems to work, but when I use the volume on a docker container:

```
docker run --name MariaDB -v MariaDBData:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecretpassword --network bridged -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:latest
```

I get `/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: SELinux relabeling of /var/lib/docker/volumes/MariaDBDataNFS/_data is not allowed: "operation not supported"` 
as output.
I've already tried settings permissive, but that didn't work.

Additional Information:
OS: CentOS7
Docker Version: 1.13.1

Comment: You probably have to use `virt_use_nfs` boolean (`setsebool virt_use_nfs 1`). If it works, I can write an answer.

Comment: @sebasth Thanks for trying to help! But unfortunately that doesn't work. It still shows "SELinux relabeling of /var/lib/docker/volumes/MariaDBData/_data is not allowed: "operation not supported"."

Comment: Also when I try to mount it directly without a external volume with `docker run --name MariaDB --volume-driver=nfs -v preisschild-server-2.lan/mnt/tank/MariaDB:/var/lib/mysql ...` It gives me `/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: create preisschild-server-2.lan/mnt/tank/MariaDB: create preisschild-server-2.lan/mnt/tank/MariaDB: Error looking up volume plugin nfs: legacy plugin: plugin not found.`

Comment: Are there relevant AVC messages in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?

Comment: @sebasth The only line I get when i do docker-run is `type=VIRT_CONTROL msg=audit(1542470519.281:11343): pid=1755 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 msg='op=create vm-pid=? user=root exe=? ctr_id_short=? reason=api vm=? auid=0 hostname=?  exe="/usr/bin/dockerd-current" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success''`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
docker run --name MariaDB -v MariaDBData:/var/lib/mysql:z -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecretpassword --network bridged -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:latest
```

OR

```
docker run --name MariaDB -v MariaDBData:/var/lib/mysql:Z -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecretpassword --network bridged -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:latest
```

OR

Disable Selinux before running the command

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `docker-current` I assume that you're on RHEL(7) and SELinux is configured (either Enforcing or Permissive).

I think you've been hit by this bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1492113#c0

At the bottom of the linked comment you can find the workaround, which I'm happily pasting also here.
Use the `nocopy` option instead of `z` or `Z`:

`docker run --name MariaDB -v MariaDBData:/var/lib/mysql:nocopy -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecretpassword --network bridged -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:latest`

See this great github comment to get a grasp of what nocopy is about.
https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/2992#issuecomment-299596714